# String Tokenizer.nextElement for JComboBox

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I'm using
 `int TxtAge = Integer.parseInt(tfAge.getText().trim());` 
to get value from my textfield and search it in database.

Then, I'm using `Integer age = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());` to go to next attributes in my database.

I have no problem using those codes for textfield but when I'm using the `JComboBox` the result won't display. How to use the `StringTokenizer.nextElement()` for `JComboBox`? Is is the same with `TextField`?

```
String sex=(String) stringTokenizer.nextElement();
```

I tried this code but still failed :(

Comment: Please take a look at the new formatting by hitting the edit button. Look for markdown syntax on meta.stackoverflow.com for more information. Please don't forget to add a tag for your programming language. And welcome to stackoverflow, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have left out the relevant portions of your code, i.e. how you are handling setting/getting items in the `JComboBox`. Whether you read these values from a database, a file or have them hardcoded is irrelevant to the question.

Since you do ask whether it is the same as with a `JTextField`, I can at least answer this; it is *not* the same. The question indicates that you're quite new to Swing. You would probably benefit from working through a basic Swing tutorial, just to get a grip on how to work with these basic GUI elements. For JComboBox, check out Oracles own [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Anyways, when working with `JComboBox`, you will need to first populate it with the values that users can choose from and set the currently selected value. Retrieving the currently selected value is just a simple method call.

Further, you have the possibility of making a combobox editable. This means that the user can edit the text in the combo box to something that was not pre-populated. By default, this option is turned off.

I'll provide some examples.

Initialize:

```
JComboBox sexComboBox = new JComboBox();
sexComboBox.addItem("Not selected");
sexComboBox.addItem("Male");
sexComboBox.addItem("Female");
sexComboBox.addItem("Do not want to disclose");
```

By default, the first item you added is selected. To select another one, you need to add one of the following lines:

```
sexComboBox.setSelectedIndex(1); // zero-based index, "Male" is selected item
sexComboBox.setSelectedItem("Female"); // sets the selected item to "Female"
```

To enable user to edit the contents to something that was not pre-defined, just add the line:

```
sexComboBox.setEditable(true);
```

To retrieve the currently selected value:

```
String selectedItem = (String) sexComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working. I still unable to retrieve the value from JComboBox :(

Comment: I still had the problem in this code
    String sex=(String) stringTokenizer.nextElement();

Comment: That's not so strange, since the stringTokenizer has nothing to do with the combo box. To retrieve the selected value in the combo box you need to do what I have shown in the last code sample: `String selectedItem = (String) sexComboBox.getSelectedItem();`

Comment: I still don't know what is wrong with my code. If don't mind can you please take a look at them?